# Get the primes in given range with provided conditions

Tags: java, algorithm

This was asked during my interview. I have to write a program to find all the prime numbers which are having only odd digits in them for the given range.

```
Eg: 31 is a prime number having only odd digits in it 3 & 1.
Eg: 23 is a prime number but it is not having odd digits in it, because it has digit 2.
```

Now I have one more constraint, to my program, I will pass a variable called `temp`.

> Now if this temp is `1` then I should find the primes, with digits containing only `<= 5`.
>
> If this temp is `2` then I should find the primes, with digits containing only `>= 5`.

**Sample Input:**

If the start position is `30` & end position is `40` with temp value as `1`. The possible prime numbers are `31`, `37` in the `30` to `40`.

```
31 prime has digits 3 & 1 => so these digits are <= 5. 
Now if my temp input data is `1` then the program should return me 1.
If suppose my temp input data is `2` then the program should return me 0.
```

37 is a prime number with digits 3 & 7. Here 3 <=5 and 7 >= 5. So we should not count this prime number as it will not fall under any category defined for my temp variable.

> So for input values start=30, end = 40, temp = 1 output should be 1.
>   (because of prime number 31).

I have come up with the below code:

```
public static int process(int start, int end, int temp) {
    List<Integer> matching = new ArrayList<>();

    // loop from start to end
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        // 0 & 1 are not primes so skip them
        if (i == 1 || i == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Check if the number is a prime
        if (isPrime(i)) {

            // Get the digits of that prime number Eg: 31 has digits 3 & 1
            List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
            buildDigits(i, nums);


            // Codition to check if we need to consider this prime or not in our result.
            boolean flag = true;
            for (Integer num : nums) {

                // The prime number is has an even digit, so discard it.
                if (num % 2 == 0) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }

                // The prime has a digit > 5 where as the restriction falls under step 1, so discard
                if (temp == 1 && num > 5) {
                    flag = false;
                }

                // The prime has a digit < 5 where as the restriction falls under step 2, so discard
                if (temp == 2 && num < 5) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }

            // Get the required primes
            if (flag) {
                matching.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    // Return their count
    return matching.size();
}

// Find out all digits in a given number, and put them in the list called nums
public static void buildDigits(int num, List<Integer> nums) {
    if (num / 10 > 0) {
        buildDigits(num / 10, nums);
    }
    nums.add(num % 10);
}

// This just finds out if the given input is prime or not
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
    if (n <= 3) {
        return true;
    }

    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6) {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I above code, I have used this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-check-if-a-number-is-prime-or-not/) as basis for `isPrime` to find prime or not.

When I used this code in my interview it cleared only 3 test cases out of 8. The test cases are hidden, I was not clear for what inputs this logic failed.

I have gone through this code in debug mode also, but I was not able to find where I made mistake.

Comment: You said the test case (start=30, end=40, temp=1) should give an output of 1.  Sounds right to me... So what result do you _actually_ get?

Comment: There is literally no reason to, at this point in time, compute those values anymore. You just load any of a thousand files with all the primes you need, precomputed, and then you filter that list instead.

Comment: I checked your code with start=0, end=999999, and both values of `temp`. It correctly identifies the prime numbers that meet the constraints. So something else is wrong. Maybe you misunderstood the requirements (e.g. `end` is not included in the range). Or maybe the code is too slow, and times out. Or maybe they deliberately passed invalid values for `start`, `end`, or `temp`, and your code didn't handle that correctly.

Comment: @KevinAnderson, it is working for some test cases and the above-given sample, but it is failing for other cases which are hidden during the interview.

Comment: @user3386109, `maybe they deliberately passed invalid values for start, end, or temp, and your code didn't handle that correctly.` This may be the reason

Comment: @user3386109, you mentioned `I checked your code with start=0, end=999999, and both values of temp.` Since the range is high, then how to identify the result I am getting is correct or not. Because there can be many prime numbers in that range and only few of them matches my above requirement. So how to know which are valid and which are not by just looking at the data. Can you please suggest.

Comment: @learner I wrote code to solve the problem using different techniques. For example, instead of trial division to find primes, I used [the sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). And I also printed all the primes that met the constraints (there are only 169 when temp is 1, and 137 when temp is 2). Since my output matched yours, and the printed numbers looked reasonable, I believe that your code is correct.

Comment: Is it possible, that you didn't pass because of wrong output, but because of timing restrictions? If timing was an issue, you could have skipped many costly primalty checks by checking the conformance of the digits first, or even don't generate such numbers at all. Or was timing/performance no issue in the test?

Comment: Note that if the range is 414234626 to 470954379, the answer is immediately 0, because every number in that range starts with 4. More generally, if the range covers all nine digit numbers (0 to 999999999) there are only 29523 numbers that need to be checked. So it's possible to achieve huge performance gains by taking a radically different approach.

Comment: You should check if the number is acceptable *before* checking if it's prime.